# Uitableview won't scroll doing for loop

Tags: ios, uitableview, for-loop

I noticed my uitableview won't respond to user interaction while performing CPU intensive O of N^3 for loops.

Is there a dispatch_async I should know about to have both my for loops and user interaction happening at the same time?

It looks like what I am looking for is called

```
 QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED
```

Via http://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1

Answer (score 1):

As a basic rule, you should:

1. Only perform UI operations (such as setting the background colour of a view, or changing the text of a label) on the main thread.
2. Perform long operations, such as your intensive loops, on a background thread.

By default, nearly everything in your app will happen on the main (UI) thread unless you tell it otherwise. You're correct in that you can use `dispatch_async` to perform your loops on a background thread to free up the main thread for processing the UI. You can for example (in Swift):

```swift
// Process something large, jump to background thread:
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), {
    
    // Long loop...
    for var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i {
        // ...
    }
    
    // When finished, jump back to main thread to update UI with results:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        myLabel.text = "Finished processing!"
    })
    
})
```